# MySQL: concatenating values in a group

Tags: mysql

Here is data from Category Table of my Database

```
Category_Name     | SubCategory_Name
Category1         | Vegetarian
Category1         | Seafood
Category1         | Lamb
Category2         | Vegetarian 
Category2         | Chicken 
Category3         | Non-Vegetarian
Category3         | Vegetarian
Category3         | Chicken
Category4         | Lamb/Goat
Category4         | Seafood
Category5         | Vegetarian
Category5         | Non-Vegetarian 
Category6         | 
Category7         | Non-Vegetarian
Category7         | Vegetarian
```

Blank values imply "no sub-categories" but the results for these categories should display in as a row mentioning only category name

I want to write a query to display the results like this:

```
Category_Name | SubCategory_Name 1 | SubCategory_Name 2 | SubCategoryName3
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: You want those in multiple columns or just as a string separated by `|`?

Comment: Do they need to be in separate columns?  Would not [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) suffice?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! An old wiseman once feed a man some fish and he will starve for 100 years, teach a man to fish and he will eat for 100 years. Everyone needs help but we cant just do your work for you. We want to see what you have done and we can guide you and help you get their.

Comment: This is trivially easy via mysql's `GROUP_CONCAT()` if you are willing to accept them combined as a single string, which you then separate out in your application code.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level (e.g. with a bit of PHP)

Comment: Can you have more than 3 subcategories ?

Comment: @Quassnoi - I think the amended title is an assumption too far.

Comment: @Strawberry: sure, but still better than "challenge". Challenge, my eye.

Comment: My SQL skills are very poor. Thats why a friend referred me to Stack Overflow. I'm overwhelmed with the quick responses. I'm looking for multiple columns, not a string separated by a character. GROUP_CONTACT wouldn't produce the desired result. Help!

Answer (score 0):

The query text will need to "know" ahead of time, the number of columns to be returned. Is three the maximum number of SubCategory_Name per Category_Name?

To handle an indeterminate number, you could combine them into a single column, using the GROUP_CONCAT function, with something like this:

```
SELECT Category_Name
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT SubCategory_Name ORDER BY SubCategory_Name) AS sc
  FROM mytable
 GROUP BY Category_Name
```

To return them as separate column would require more work. We'd first need to have an "upper limit" on the number of columns to be returned.

We can first get a list of distinct Category_Name, and then for each of those, run a correlated subquery to retrieve the 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc. SubCategory_Name associated with each.

This can very inefficient with large sets, but it performs reasonable with small sets, and does return the specified resultset:

```
SELECT g.Category_Name
     , ( SELECT s1.SubCategory_Name
           FROM mytable s1
          WHERE s1.Category_Name = t.Category_Name
          GROUP BY s1.SubCategory_Name
          ORDER BY s1.SubCategory_Name
          LIMIT 0,1
       ) AS `SubCategory_Name 1`
     , ( SELECT s2.SubCategory_Name
           FROM mytable s2
          WHERE s2.Category_Name = t.Category_Name
          GROUP BY s2.SubCategory_Name
          ORDER BY s2.SubCategory_Name
          LIMIT 1,1
       ) AS `SubCategory_Name 2`
     , ( SELECT s3.SubCategory_Name
           FROM mytable s3
          WHERE s3.Category_Name = t.Category_Name
          GROUP BY s3.SubCategory_Name
          ORDER BY s3.SubCategory_Name
          LIMIT 2,1
       ) AS `SubCategory_Name 3`
  FROM ( SELECT t.Category_Name
           FROM mytable t 
          GROUP BY t.Category_Name
       ) g
 ORDER BY g.Category_Name
```

To return the 4th, 5th etc. subcategory, you would copy the correlated subquery and change it to `LIMIT 3,1` to get the fourth,  `LIMIT 4,1` to get the fifth,

Comment: The first query runs fine.. I'm interested in the second one more as it would return the resultset I'm looking for. When I run the second sql statement, it returns the following error: #1054 - Unknown column 't.Category_Name' in 'where clause'.